# Is there any JSP equivalent for text editor as we use in ASP.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, jsp

i am designing a website where user can enter text in a formatted way, i have worked in asp.net where i have used AJAX toolkit and used HTML text editor control. i require similar kind of feature but i don't know how to achieve this feature in jsp.

As you will be answering this question you will be doing some formatting below, i just want to implement the similar kind of feature.

I couldn't show my work as this problem is what i have to solve first. Please let me know how can i do this.  !
but i am talking of the answer box of stack overflow or similar 
[image]

thanx...

Answer (score 0):

If you want a free version then use [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/). It is fast and uses jquery and setting it up is really easy and you can buy it to activate other features too.

But if you want to pay for it then you can use [Cute Editor](http://cutesoft.net/ASP.NET+WYSIWYG+Editor/), from my experience you need to buy licence per domain.

Answer (score 0):

javascript editor

1. jHtmlArea http://jhtmlarea.codeplex.com/
2. ckeditor http://ckeditor.com/
3. tinymce http://www.tinymce.com/
4. http://medleyweb.com/resources/10-best-free-javascript-or-jquery-wysiwyg-html-editors/